# "NodeJS as an avenue towards learning JavaScript" closure

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[NodeJS as an avenue towards learning JavaScript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184404/nodejs-as-an-avenue-towards-learning-javascript)

This is a question that only someone who knows both JavaScript and Node fairly in-depth could answer properly. I would call that "specific expertise" and am confused by the closure of this question. Favorite books is one thing. I don't see a problem with somebody asking whether a given path to take in learning a new technology might be less productive than another within the context of that specific technology based on people's experience.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't vote to close, but I imagine the thought was there can be no definitive answer to the question. Some will say "Yes, it's a great idea to learn JavaScript through Node," and some will say "No, that's stupid."

I occasionally enjoy the insights that arise from such questions, but the community seems less enthusiastic, especially the busy bodies who work hard to make P.SE what it is.

Comment: But professional insight is never going to be definitive. You can only speak in terms of opinion founded on experience. People in a given field will tend to fall in line with a lot of the same practices but not always. Isn't that distinction what separates stack from programmers?

Comment: @ErikReppen There's a good question in there, and I think the closure came (mostly) because of the answers that focus on the merits of learning JavaScript instead of the _actual_ question.

Comment: @YannisRizos Yeah, this closing for the answers phenomenon is something I've seen in a couple places and I don't even pay close attention to Meta. I don't like that at all. Mods should respond to lousy answers with downvotes, comments, or better answers, not closures. Answers might tip you off to a bad question but when it comes time to close you should be looking at the question only IMO.

Comment: @ErikReppen The problem here is that the answers aren't lousy, they are good answers to a slightly different question. I think when the answers are good but venture off topic, it's a sign that the question is a bit misleading and/or confusing. Which isn't something that we can't fix by editing.